# curve of constant curvature on unit sphere is planar curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, frenet-frame

I've studied differential geometry and get this question.

I'd like to verify following statement.

> **curve of constant curvature on unit sphere is planar curve**

I've struggled with Frenet-Serret frame, differentiating, differentiating, differentiating, .....

BUT I didn't get something yet..

Could you give me some hint, please?

$$
$$
Ah!! FIRST OF ALL,

I'd like to know whether the statement is true or false.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to show that the torsion is zero.
Note that If $\mathbf{r}$ is the unit radius vector to the curve then 
$$\mathbf{t}=\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{ds}$$
Now $\mathbf{t} \cdot \mathbf{r}=0$ so on differentiating we get

$$\frac{d \mathbf{t}}{ds}\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{t}\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{ds}=0$$
or $$\kappa \mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{r}+ \mathbf{t}\cdot \mathbf{t}=0$$
(Note that $\kappa\neq 0$, since otherwise we have a straight line.)
So $$\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{r}=-\frac{1}{\kappa}$$ differentiating this and using that $\kappa$ is constant we get

$$(-\kappa \mathbf{t}+\tau \mathbf{b})\cdot \mathbf{r}+\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{t}=0$$
which simplifies to 
$$\tau \mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{r}=0$$
If $\tau=0$ we are done so assume

$$\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{r}=0$$

and differentiate
which gives

$$-\tau \mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{r}+\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{t}=0$$

$$-\tau \mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{r}=0$$
But $\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{r}=-\frac{1}{\kappa}$ so again $\tau=0$.

Comment: so clear... THANK you very much.

Comment: It was a pleasure.