# General solution of this system of differential equations describing a particle moving on a sphere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How can I find a general 3D solution $\vec{x}(t)$ for the following system of differential equations?

$\left|\vec{x}(t)\right| = c_0\\
\left|\frac{d \vec{x}(t)}{dt}\right| = c_1\\
\left|\frac{d^2 \vec{x}(t)}{dt^2}\right| = c_2$

where $c_0,c_1, c_2$ are constants. I'm most interested in the 3D case which means that we are dealing with a particle on a sphere moving at a constant absolute value of velocity and a constant absolute value of acceleration.

Comment: How many elements does $\vec x$ have? In 2 or fewer dimensions, the equation generically has no solution. In higher dimensions, the behavior of the solutions becomes more complex

Comment: In physical terms, you are describing the behavior of a particle traveling on the $n$ dimensional sphere, at a constant magnitude velocity, with a constant magnitude force applied at all times...  So, for instance in the case of $n=2$, $x=(sin(t), cos(t))$ would satisfy the equations. For a sphere, I can imagine a particle "spiraling" up and down the surface. It would be interesting to see what higher dimensional schemes would look like.

Comment: @player100 Yes, that's exactly the situation I have in mind. I'm most interested in the 3D case. I edited my question to make that more clear.

Comment: For the 2D case, you do not have enough degrees of freedom to have $c_2$ be independently varied. $x=c_0(sin \omega t, cos \omega t)$, and $\omega = \frac{c_1}{c_0}$. Thus $c_2=\omega^2 c_0$. Note some general relationships: $x^tv=0$ and $v^ta=0$. Also, $x^ta+v^tv = 0$. These should hold true in all dimensions. In 2D $a$ is the centripetal force. The 2D solutions should hold true in 3D, and are thus one solution set. I am trying to see if there are acceleration vectors are not strictly aligned with the position vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scaling $x$ you may assume $c_0=1$, and after scaling $t$ you may assume $c_1=1$. We then have a curve
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto x(t)\in S^2$$
parametrized by arc length. Since in this case $|\ddot x(t)|=\kappa(t)$ the third condition says that the curvature of $\gamma$ is constant. Intuition then tells us that $\gamma$ has to be a circle. That this is indeed the case is proven, e.g., in the  answer to the following MSE question:

[curve of constant curvature on unit sphere is planar curve?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856381/curve-of-constant-curvature-on-unit-sphere-is-planar-curve)